# how to pass Arraylist <uri > insted of integer in array in viewpager

Tags: android, arraylist, android-viewpager

I am trying to load images from sd card in view pager . I have got the arrayList of uri . How to change my code to open these images instead of drawables.

my mainAvtivity class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);
    mCustomPageAdapter = new CustomPageAdapter(this);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPageAdapter);
}
public class CustomPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    public CustomPageAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resourceIDs.length;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item,container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(resourceIDs[position]);
        container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have `ArrayList<Uri> uriList`. Now change the code like this:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);
        mCustomPageAdapter = new CustomPageAdapter(this);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPageAdapter);
    }
    public class CustomPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        Context mContext;
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
        public CustomPageAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
            mLayoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return uriList.size();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item,container, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageURI((uriList.get(position));
            container.addView(itemView);
            return itemView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think. You either dont have the authority to the uri or your uri is null. Check the logcat.

Comment: Thank you very much . It worked. I was passing null uri. Now its running perfectly

Comment: @viditwadhwa Can you please also upvote the answer? This may help other people.